# Why do flow-typed libdefs types not work consistently?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, flowtype, react-router-v4, flow-typed

I have a React project using Flow for static type checking; I have libdefs for npm 3rd party libraries installed using `flow-typed`. However, sometimes the types are not recognized. For example, here is a React component using the `react-router-dom` npm package, with a `identifier ... Could not resolve name` Flow error when using the type from the corresponding `flow-typed/npm/react-router-dom_v4.x.x.js`:

[image: flow error]

The type is in the libdef though:

[image: react-router-dom flow-typed]

I'm doing this with other `flow-typed` types and it is working. I've confirmed that I have the latest library installed in `package.json` and the latest related `flow-typed` libdef installed:

[image: package.json lateset react-router-dom]

[image: flow-typed latest react-router-dom]

From https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/tree/master/definitions/npm/react-router-dom_v4.x.x

I've also tried explicitly importing the type like an ES6 module like this:

`` import type { RouterHistory } from 'react-router-dom'` ``

But this leads to a `RouterHistory not found in 'react-router-dom'` error, even though you can see in the screenshot above that it exists in the `react-router-dom_v4.x.x.js` libdef from `flow-typed/npm/`; I believe that explicit imports of types only work if the npm library has `*.js.flow` files inside it (which `react-router-dom` does not but is defined in `flow-typed`).

So the question is: **why doesn't the `RouterHistory` type work if it is defined in the related `flow-typed` libdef**?

Comment: You'll absolutely need that import line at the end of your question. Once you do that, what error do you get?

Comment: Why is the import line needed? All of the other libdefs I'm using in `flow-typed` work without type imports. Like I can use `SyntheticEvent` from React. Even so, adding `import type { RouterHistory } from 'react-router-dom'` leads to the `RouterHistory not found in 'react-router-dom'` error, even though the `RouterHistory` type is in the `react-router-dom_v4.x.x.js` `flow-typed` file, as shown in the question's screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Your import statement is wrong. It should be like this:

```
import type { RouterHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
```

EDIT:

It seems that the RouterHistory type is in the react-router package. Since react-router-dom uses react-router as a base dependency you should add the react-router package with flow-typed.
[Flow-React-Router](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-router_v4.x.x/flow_v0.38.x-/react-router_v4.x.x.js)

Comment: That leads to a different error: `RouterHistory not found in 'react-router-dom'`. `react-router-dom` doesn't have `*.js.flow` files in it so this wouldn't work right?

Comment: Ah okey, it seems that the RouterHistory type is not part of the react-router-dom package. Instead you should install the react-router package via flow-typed. I edited my answer.

Comment: As shown in the screenshots, `RouterHistory` is in the `react-router-dom_v4.x.x.js` `flow-typed` file https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7mMr.png

Comment: You can see that it exists here: https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-router-dom_v4.x.x/flow_v0.38.x-/react-router-dom_v4.x.x.js#L62